# Can I change Schengen visa type during visa process?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, germany

I am Indian student studying in a science institute in India. For doing summer internship in physics for 3 months, professor in Germany has enrolled me in TU Dresden.

I applied for  short stay internship Schengen visa and got a mail 15 days later that I have to submit ZAV/work permit to get the visa.

As I am enrolled as student and also paid sommersemster fees I don't require work permit. Did I apply to wrong sub-visa type? If yes how do I change it, documents are still at German embassy Delhi.

I have already missed a flight because of the delay in my visa and my prof is really angry at me. What should I do?